# Actionscript 3 does not work .. it didn't give errors

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I am creating a clock using this code:

```
var date:Date = new Date();
var time:Timer = new Timer(1000); 
time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, actualiser);
time.start();

function actualiser(e:TimerEvent){
    date = new Date();
    var s:uint = date.seconds;
    var m:uint = date.minutes;
    var h:uint = date.hours;
    sec_mc.rotation =(s * 6);
    min_mc.rotation =(m * 6);
    heur_mc.rotation =(h * 30) +m/2;
}
```

But, it seems that the code is not executing, I can’t even trace anything written in constructor of my document class. When I run it nothing happens and when I try to debug  I get the alert message saying:

> You cannot debug this SWF because it does not contain ActionScript

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try to check the code in a new fla. Write the following in your **1st frame action panel**. This does give proper output and you can see the traces in the **output panel**. There is no issue with the code logic. Might be some issue with the movieclip being used.

```
var date:Date = new Date();
var time:Timer = new Timer(1000); 
time.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, actualiser);
time.start();

    function actualiser(e:TimerEvent){
        date = new Date();
        var s:uint = date.seconds;
        var m:uint = date.minutes;
        var h:uint = date.hours;
        trace(h+":"+m+":"+s);
    }
```

In case of CS5 , try the following steps :

WINDOWS:

**1.** Quit Flash
**2.** In a text editor, open the **jvm.ini** file from the following location:

**2.1. Windows XP:** System Hard Disk\Documents and Settings\user\Local Settings\Application Data\Adobe\Flash CS5\language\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\jvm.ini

**2.2.** **Windows Vista or Windows7:** System Hard Disk\Users\user\AppData\Local\Adobe\Flash CS5\language\Configuration\ActionScript 3.0\jvm.ini

(You might need to turn on “show hidden files”)
**3.** Change **-Xmx128m to -Xmx256m** and save the file.

Comment: i try that but  it trace nothing still the same problem  it seems that the code was not executing with that alert message 'You cannot debug this SWF because it does not contain ActionScript'

Comment: which **FLASH IDE** are you using ? CS4/CS5 ?

Comment: Id say its the pc itself(software) the above code is correct.restart pc and try again something could have crashed if not reinstall a legit copy, lol

Comment: hhhh i did i restart pc and i try again but sometimes raaaarely it work just for the first run  :/ im sick of that i don't know where is the problem  !!! :(

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Uhm. Is that all you have? Because you need to import the needed packages, etc. Also, are you sure you linked everything up?

Comment: i did  that's the code of clock is totally correct that's what my professor told me but he didn't have any idea why when   I try to debug it  I get the alert message  but the problem is not in the code is in every file .fla which contain ActionScript

Comment: Add the imports, file name, and class name.

Comment: well i don't have class to add !!

Comment: My friend. You must nest everything inside a class, in an .as file. And you need imports.

Comment: thanx i know but the problem is that flash can’t even trace anything written in constructor of my document class like i say before !! for example if i forget a semicolon of write something wrong flash didn't give me any errors :(